# LibGDX/Java Game - Making 4 random colors

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d-games

I'm making a game using LibGDX and the idea of the game is there's four buttons with 4 different colors on them ( red, green, yellow, and blue ). Then there's a circle that goes across the bottom of the screen that is one of the 4 colors and you select what color it is before it hits the end of the screen and if you successfully do so it resets as a different color and you repeat this until you lose ( It also goes faster the more points you get ). Where I'm stuck is, I want to add a feature for every time you get a point it will randomize the 4 buttons colors. Here's a diagram.

[image: diagram1]

[image: diagram2]

My problem is I don't know how I would ranomize these colors without two or more of them turning out as the same color. The way I randomized the bottom color is just using `int RandomColor = MathUtils.random(1, 4);` then based on what number that becomes is what color it becomes, for example, 1 = red, 2 = blue, ect.

Comment: Would it work for you to have a stock of, say, 20 colours that are all quite different from each other; and then pick four of them at random?

Comment: That might make the game more interesting

Comment: Oh, did you just mean that you keep red, yellow, green and blue; but swap them round?  Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think shuffling might be helpful.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array with 4 cells (for every "tile").
2. Have a list ([ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) - both have pros and cons, you should definitely read about them) with all of the available tiles (reference them as names, ids or objects, it doesn't really matter).
3. Randomly pick one of the list items, and insert it into the first cell of the array, then remove this item from the list.
4. Follow step 3 until the list is empty.
5. Reinitialize the list for further use.

As you stated, you already realized how to pick the random circle which moves below the tiles.

Comment: Will try this, if I get it to work the way I want it I will check this as the answer.